# EWS Mark mail as read after moving

Tags: powershell, email, exchangewebservices

With the help of Exchange Web Services we're trying to move a mail to a specific folder and then mark it as read. To do this we use the following code:

```
Write-Verbose "Move mail to '$('\PowerShell\' + $SQLTickets.ScriptName)'"
$DestinationPathID = Find-MailboxFolderIDHC @FindMailParams -Path ('\PowerShell\' + $SQLTickets.ScriptName)
$Mail.Move($DestinationPathID) | Out-Null

Write-Verbose 'Mark mails as read'
$Mail.IsRead = $true
$Mail.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AutoResolve)
```

When I check the result of this action the mail is indeed correctly moved to the folder en has the `IsRead` property set to `True`. However, this is not visible in MS Outlook, it's still not marked as `Read`.

When it hits this line:

```
$Mail.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AutoResolve)
```

It throws the follwing error which I can't seem to fix:

```
Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "The specified object was not found in the store."
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of operations so that the `Move()` operation is very last?

Comment: Yes. that does seem to do the trick. Just tried it again and marking first as read then moving seems to be doing the job. Thx for the tip!

Comment: From the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange    When you move or copy an email message into a different folder, a new item is created in the new folder with a unique item ID, and the original message is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark it read first, then move it like this:

```
$Mail.IsRead = $true
$Mail.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AutoResolve)
[VOID]$Mail.Move($DestinationPathID)
```